# Maven SQL-Plugin runs multiple times in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project as shown below:

```
            Module
            |_________sub-module1
            |                   |___pom.xml          
            |_________sub-module2
            |                   |___pom.xml
            |_________sub-module3
            |                   |___pom.xml
            |_________sub-module4
            |                   |___pom.xml
            |_________pom.xml
```

I have added some sql scripts for create and drop integration test data in the sub-module2. In the parent pom, I have the below code to setup the database for the integration test.

```
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>

                    <configuration>
                        <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:blah</url>
                        <settingsKey>sqlsrv-integration-test-creds</settingsKey>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>

                        <execution>
                            <id>create-integration-test-data</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                                <fileset>
                                    <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources</basedir>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>create-integration-test-data.sql</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>drop-db-after-test</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>execute</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <fileset>
                                    <basedir>${basedir}/src/test/resources</basedir>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>drop-integration-test-data.sql</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>

</plugin>
```

Now, when I run `mvn clean install`, I am getting error that the file doesn't exist in **sub-module1**. So I tried adding the scripts to sub-module1. Now, it got executed in **sub-module1**, but also in **sub-module2** and in **sub-module3**, where it failed since the scripts are not there in sub-module3.

How can I make the scripts get executed only once ?

Comment: Add the sql-maven-plugin exactly where you need it (sub-module-2) and not in the parent, cause it will be inherited and of course will be executed within every child.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments:

> Add the sql-maven-plugin exactly where you need it (sub-module-2) and
>   not in the parent, cause it will be inherited and of course will be
>   executed within every child. –  khmarbaise Jul 22 '14 at 9:25